# Можно ли обойти ошибку при динамическом имени класса?

Tags: php, ооп

Всё работает:

```
$class = 'Class'.$request->controller;
$obj  = new $class;
```

А так шторм говорит синтаксическая и страница плюётся 500й ошибкой:

```
$obj  = new 'Class'.$request->controller;
```

Цель - избавится от доп. переменной и визуального мусора (дополнительной строчки в коде)

Comment: и что пишется в сообщениях об ошибке шторма к примеру? где подчеркивает синтаксис?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Expected: class name Expression is calculated but result not using anywhere

Comment: это не то. но емнип, по-другому (без дополнительно вводимой переменной) нельзя создать класс из строки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

язык php поддерживает [обращение к функциям через переменные](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.variable-functions.php), то же самое и с классами.

Вы можете создать переменную.

```
$class = 'Class'.$request->controller;
```

И потом создать класс, с помощью переменной.

```
$obj  = new $class;
```

А в Вашем случае `'Class'.$request->controller` это строка, а не переменная php

Comment: у него в вопросе это и написано

Comment: @Ипатьев что написано, что "Цель - избавится от доп. переменной"? Так в данном контексте это невозможно